# Pandas: Replace pattern in column values with list values

Tags: pandas, regex, dataframe, replace

Stuck on the following in Pandas...
I have the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['aaCHANGEMEbb', 'nnANDMEdd', 'hhMETOOkk'], 'index': ['a', 'b', 'c']}).set_index('index')

           col1
a  aaCHANGEMEbb
b     nnANDMEdd
c      hhXXXXkk
```

And I want to change all uppercase cases in column `'col1'` with values from `m_list:`

```
m_list = ['1.0', '2.0', '3.0']
```

One of my attempt that seems as something that is near to truth:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace('[A-Z]+', lambda x: [i for i in m_list], regex=True)
```

And another one:

```
df['col1'].str.replace('([A-Z]+)', lambda x: m_list[x.group(0)])
```

It doesn't work. I got this in both cases:

```
   col1
a   NaN
b   NaN
c   NaN
```

But the expected df below:

```
         col1
a     aa1.0bb
b     nn2.0dd
c     hh3.0kk
```

Please, share your thoughts about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with `split`

```
s = df['col1'].str.split(r'([A-Z]+)',expand=True)
s.loc[:,1] = m_list
df['col1'] = s.agg(''.join,1)
df
Out[255]: 
          col1
index         
a      aa1.0bb
b      nn2.0dd
c      hh3.0kk
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for idx, x in enumerate(m_list):
    df.loc[idx] = re.sub(r'([A-Z]+)', x, df.loc[idx][0])
```